# Does this code causes UB?

Tags: c++

I have checkd gcc and clang and both does not generate any warnings. I suppose that lifetime of temporary from foo() will be prolonged untill the end of full expression which is where semicolon in bar function call is located.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A
{
    std::string foo() const{ return "aaa"; }
};

void bar(const char* c) {
    std::cout << c;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    bar(a.foo().c_str()); // Is this safe?
    bar(a.foo().substr().c_str()); // or this
}
```

Comment: yes, you're right, it's safe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The temporary returned by `foo()` (and `substr()`) will continue to exist until the end of the `bar` call (after the chain of method calls), this is safe.

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    bar(a.foo().c_str()); 
    //temporary is destroyed here
    bar(a.foo().substr().c_str()); 
    // and here
}
```

Classical undefined behaviour case :

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    const char* charPtr = a.foo().c_str();
    printf("%s", charPtr);
}
```

Temporary `std::string` is created, a pointer to it's buffer is returned by `c_str()` and the temporary goes out of scope and is destroyed. `charPtr` now is a pointer pointing to an invalid location ( a dead `std::string` ).

Comment: UB example is not exactly right. charPtr remains valid until a non-const operation is called on a.

Comment: @Trevir `printf` trying to use it to print it out should be just enough.

Comment: How does printf interfer with object a?

Comment: @Trevir It doesn't but it doesn't have to? `charPtr` is pointing to invalid memory, `printf` will try to deref that, that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: as I pointed out, charPtr is valid until a non const operation is invoked on object a.

Comment: @Trevir: There is UB unrelated to what happens to `a`. Lifetime of the `std::string` returned by `foo` ends before the call to `printf`. (and so `charPtr` is a dangling pointer).

Comment: Yeah right. I oversaw foo() returning a temporary ...

Answer (score 4):

```
bar(a.foo().c_str());
bar(a.foo().substr().c_str());
```

Short answer - Yes, both are safe.

What you're looking at is an *rvalue*.

> An rvalue (so-called, historically, because rvalues could appear on the right-hand side of an assignment expression) is an xvalue, a temporary object or subobject thereof, or a value that is not associated with an object.

Read more: [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: It being an rvalue isn't really the point

Comment: isnt? c_str() returns a pointer into an rvalue object. so it kinda matters. if you save this pointer, its dangerous!